# RSpec and FactoryGirl

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, factory-bot, rspec-rails

I currently have an RSpec test:

```
    Rspec.describe Some::ServiceClass do 
      args = ['1', '2']
      subject { described_class.new(args) }

      describe '#finder_method' do 
        let(:user_1) { FactorGirl.create(:user) } 

        it 'returns the right number of users' do
          expect(subject.finder_method.count).to eq(1)
        end
      end
    end
```

This is what the class under test looks like

```
   module Some

      class Service

        ....
        # other methods used to identify the resource model

        def finder_method 
          resource.all
        end
      end

    end
```

**Expectation**:

- when `resource.all` is called, I expected that
- `let(:user_1) FactoryGirl.create(:user)`, in spec test, would populated 1 row in the `users` table (test env)
- therefore when `subject.finder_method` is evaluated, it would return one AR object.

**Actual Result**:

- instead `subject.finder_method`, which simply calls `all` on AR object,  returns `#<ActiveRecord::Relation []>`

Can anyone please explain why is this happening? Where is the `user_1` that was created by FactoryGirl?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ugh!!

`let` is the culprit ... totally forgot about it being lazily evaluated. I need to get some sleep :(